# Do Unity Web Apps No longer Intergrate Into the HUD?

Tags: unity, webapps, hud

Do unity-web-apps no longer integrate into the HUD ([x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jPS8.jpg)) and into the desktop ([x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXCgK.jpg))?

I haven't used unity-web-apps since 12.04, and I do not know if it is simply not working or if this is a feature that has since been removed, as I am struggle to find information on it online.

I have checked to see if `libunity-webapps0`, `unity-webapps-common` & `unity-webapps-service` are installed correctly and they appear to be.

Does any one have any information?

Thank you.

--EDIT--

I forgot to mention that I'm using 16.04 LTS